# Can I say " If you would have questions; please contact us"

Tags: grammar, conditionals

Is that a conditional sentence? Seems like it's either not conditional or just dramatically inconsistent. If it's not a good one, how can I say that if there will be any questions in the future, you can ask me. If it's good, which conditional is it?

Comment: The correct way to ask would be:" If you have any questions please contact us."

Answer (score 1):

**If you would have questions, please contact us** is a conditional sentence, but it is not grammatically correct.  (At least, not in the way you probably intend.)

We do use *would* for [conditionals](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/conditionals.html), like

> If I had a question, I would go to you.

but not in the way you are trying to use it here.

English conditionals are a little complicated, but in a [first conditional imperative](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-the-1st-first-conditional/), the verb in the first part is just in the present tense.

> If you like peas, buy some.
> If he is there, say "hello" to him for me.
> If the toilet clogs up, use the plunger.

It doesn't matter if the event is in the future; that's what the "if" is for.  You don't have to put the verb in any kind of future construction.  So it should be just

> If you **have** questions...

Because of this, the only grammatically correct way to read your original sentence is

> If you **want to have** questions, please contact us

which is probably not what you mean!

(As a side note, you are also using the semicolon (**;**) incorrectly.  It is only used to separate two complete sentences, and you should be using a comma here.)

Comment: "If you would" isn't actually a conditional, it's asking a preference.  The English verb will/would is overloaded and used both as an active verb meaning "desire" and corresponding to the noun "will" (*Where there's a will there's a way*) and alternatively as a tense modifier.  At times these two usages overlap: "He would take a limo to the airport" expresses both desire and counterfactual.

Comment: @BenVoigt  I'm thinking of "if you would" in the sense of [Live Straight If You Would Shoot Straight](https://books.google.com/books?id=MH0UwupssqAC&pg=PA3&dq=%22if+you+would%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjn9vShiJrvAhUOJt8KHW7xBC0Q6AEwAHoECAAQAg); not sure if that's what you were thinking of.

Comment: Yes, that one means "Live Straight *if You Want to* Shoot Straight".  It's not a tense modifier.  The tense modifier sense of *would* goes in the predicate, the portion which is controlled by the condition.  In your example "If I had a question, I would go to you" the condition is "whether I have a question" and the predicate is "I would go to you".  In the new sentence, the condition is "whether you would shoot straight" and the predicate is "live straight".